# Dual boot options disappeared and now just boots straight into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My netbook used to display an option to boot Ubuntu or Windows 7 but for some reason that no longer displays. Now it just boots into Ubuntu and I can't figure out how to get back into Windows. I tried updating grub2 (in terminal, I typed `sudo update-grub` and in the last line says `Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1` but restarts and still boots straight into Ubuntu. How can I boot into Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can try downloading and burning `http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/`
 on the CD, then boot that CD and something like this will show up:

[image]

Click `Recommended repair` and it will repair your grub menu options.

Read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting to see if Grub reappears.

You could also check your `/etc/default/grub` file and see if the timeouts lines are as follows:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

If they are not correct them (`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`) then run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

If your computer boots straight to Ubuntu:

Open terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

**Note**: In first command `/dev/sda6` is ubuntu `/root` partition.

No need to run boot repair using live dvd/usb